# REST and PHP session confusion

Tags: php, session, rest

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do sessions really violate RESTfulness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness)

Silly question but isn't the use of sessions in PHP opposite to the whole philosophy of a RESTful application?

In other words are you "allowed" to have sessions in a REST architecture? Because I thought that a main point of it was to be stateless.

Comment: There is a really great discussion about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness

Comment: @zerkms Thanks! Thats exactly what I was looking for..didnt see it before