# Storing login credentials in Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome-app

Is there a way to safely store login information inside a Chrome App, I think all database including IndexedDB and Sync storage is insecure?

I want to be able to provide an option where the user keys in the API key when the user first installs the app and then after just start without asking the API key at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinkg that the answer to this question can help you:

[JavaScript REST Client and session management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16329055/javascript-rest-client-and-session-management)

Basically, you want the same kind of auth as any other web app has, by generating a session key at login for the user, and then make communications between client and server by only using this key.

Do not use IndexDB or Sync storage since they're not secure (see http://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage.html)

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I guess it does answer my question, I have rethink my design, but yes it does. thanks!