# Handling restful login without HTTP AUTH

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture

I'm working on a web application, and I've decided to make serverside a(n almost) restful web service (using node.js).

I say almost restful, because while I would like to use resource paradigm, I want to be more flexible in doing certain things, namely authentication.

All articles, tutorials and examples I have read says that i should use http auth for authentication. But I have a different idea.

I made a resource named session, which works like this:

POST /session

Creates a session, and returns session id. This session id value will be used for all requests in this session. (At this point, user is not logged in, but has a session, so I can already set values for session.)

PUT /session {session, email, password}

Updates the session with a user value

DELETE /session {session}

Deletes the session, logging user out.

Here are the questions:

1. Is this session resource meaningful, or is it just taking this flexibility too far?
2. If this was truly restful, I should have included session id in requests like /session/:id, but because session is something like a singleton resource (as far as the user is concerned, there is no other session possible), so there is no harm in flexing rules this way. Is this a good idea?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness/14498345) may help