# Dart as java web application frontend, Dart http session management

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets, dart

I have a java web application with jsp frontend.
I want to use Dart as frontend instead of jsp.

I made Dart invoke java through a Jersey web service.
I had success calling the java web service and display java data in the browser through Dart HttpRequest.

In java/jsp I'm using the session to store some information.
The next step, where I'm stuck, is session management with Dart. 
I cannot manage to keep the java **session** from Dart `HttpRequest`.

Is there a way to maintain the java session from Dart `HttpRequest`?
I cannot remove the dependency from the java session and implement a REST service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved without the use of the cookies:

- I created a java web service to create/return the jsessionid string
- from Dart I call the previous web service and store the jsessionid in a local variable
- all the following Dart HttpRequest have the jsessionid in the url  like `"http://server/app/wsxyz;jsessionid=14F5FA9836512AF"`

Answer (score 1):

At Browser Side, Session is just another cookie. If you want to manipulate cookies at Browser side you should see this library:

[cookie 0.0.4](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/cookie)

Furthermore look in this answer where is explained why restful services shouldn't have sessions:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20311981/2117440

Comment: Thankyou for pointing me to cookie library.
About REST, I know it's motives; I've stated that my application cannot remove session management. Aside of that it will have 3 or 4 client at most.

Comment: The JSESSIONID cookie is not accessible, it is always null; looks like response header of HttpRequest does not affect the document