# RESTful Web API using Session

Tags: web-services, rest, restful-architecture

On my server side the User Session is stored, so this information is shared among web api calls. Since the RESTful model should be 'stateless', does this mean my web api is not RESTful anymore?

EDIT: Would this mean it's not taking full advantage of the REST model and will not scale when having lots of Session stored?

Comment: Please see the following discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness

Comment: This argument has been made a countless number of times. Some basic googling will give you all the info you can possibly want. As a start, this might help: [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions).