# REST with SOA in java

Tags: java, javascript, rest

I am planning an application that will have a web front end (maybe ember) but I want to keep my options open for a native desktop application and/or an android application. I would like the all of the backend logic to be exposed as a RESTful service.  The problem that arises in my mind is about user authentication.  Since a RESTful service can't keep state on the server, I would need to keep it on the client in javascript.  However this is wildly insecure do to the fact that users have the ability to edit the javascript data.  What is the correct way to make a client side application communicate with a RESTful backend? I realize that I could just store state on the server anyways(inside the session object), but i would like to follow the REST paradigm. What is the de facto solution for this problem?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Enable user authentication for your REST services.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Would you care to elaborate on that at all?