# RESTFul Servlets? A.K.A. What am I thinking?

Tags: jax-rs

As far as I can tell, this question is neither open-ended or looking for an opinion.

I have been banging my head off the wall for the last few days, trying to figure this out.  I've 
searched Stackoverflow, Oracle, IBM and many others., but I just can't seem to find the concept I am looking for.

When using JAX-RS:

1. How there can be a backend-model that can be used to maintain session-specific information
   such as User's current session ID, User's login name and any database activity.
2. How the servlet can have it's post/put/get functionality overridden and different paths mapped
   to offer specific functionality based on the URI (for example:  login, getmoredata, deletesomedata).

The idea of a "Restful Servlet" is sort of what I am looking for, but I just don't what the concept is called.

I've build an MVC style Web-App that almost does what I want, but I want to be able to use @Path, @POST and such to denote specific model functions to have specific tasks.

I **can't** use a framework like Spring.

Thanks

Comment: ok so its not open ended? what specific issue? what did you try? what did not work? what worked?

Comment: see if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness

Comment: Thanks Kalpesh, reading it now.   In terms of being open-ended, I don't consider it as such, because I'm really looking for the name of the concept, like for example, MVC = Model View Controller.

I'm not really looking for the code, but the technical name of what it is I am looking for.