# How to design restful register, authentication, reset password

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, restful-url

If REST uses HTTP for all four CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) operations, how should be designed(verb & path) operations like:

- register
- authentication/deauthentication
- reset password

Answer (score 1):

Register: You could regard this as creating an account: POST /.../accounts

Auth/Deauth: Do you mean creating and deleting a session? Then it's a POST and a DELETE respectively: POST /.../sessions  ;  DELETE /.../session/{sessionid}. Strictly speaking, sessions are not restful. For more information, see ["Do sessions really violate restfulness"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness).

Reset password: Can be regarded as an update of a part of the account: PATCH /.../accounts/{accountid}. If the password is a separate resource, you could do PUT instead of PATCH:  PUT /.../accounts/{accountid}/password

Comment: Thanks. By sessions I mean just a token, so it's stateless.

Comment: What if register should be in two ways, register by login and password, and register by social token. How it could be?