# Spring Boot Rest Spring Security Authentication Issue with CORS

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

I am developing a Spring REST application using Spring Boot. I am consuming the Spring REST APIs using angular JS client.

The stack I am using is :

```
Spring Boot 1.4.2 , Spring Security , Angular JS , Tomcat 8
```

My Issue Is  :

1)At login , user gets succesfully authenticated. Custom authentication success handler returns 200 status code.

2)After authentication success , when clint sends another request to access a procted resource , HttpSession is NULL

3)Due to which when `SecurityContextPersistenceFilter` tries to retrieve the `SecurityContext` from `HttpSession` it is returned as null and
 and again server sends request to `/login` resource

4)So my questions are :

1)Why is httpsesion is null for second request ?

2)I have observed that Spring security returns `JSESSIONID` as cookie after first succesfull authentication.

3)But after that , client is NOT sending this `JSESSIONID` in request hence second request won't be in same session.

4)If that is the case , how is `SecurityContext` will be retrieved if `SESSION` is not established ?

Please help as I am not able to proceed here

**EDIT 1 :**

I am using default in memory user provided by spring security. My security configuration is bellow :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan({"com.atul.security"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private RESTAuthenticationSuccessHandler authenticationSuccessHandler;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
          http
            .formLogin().successHandler(authenticationSuccessHandler)
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

}
```

I am getting below user as authenticated user :

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055c2bc: 
Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; 
Authenticated: true; 
Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: 
RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; 
SessionId: null; 
Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

The request is now failing at : `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` : `AccessDecisionVoter` returning false for `authenticated` expression and access denied exception is thrown

Comment: Did you disabled the csrf token security?

Comment: Yes I did that while configuring spring security

Comment: @Atul : Do you know meaning of this : and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);

Comment: Yes. It means session will never be created by spring security and that means form based login will not work. I will remove STATELESS and try

Answer (score 1):

**There is no session in rest because RESTFUL services don't maintain state, *read this stack overflow post:***

[Do sessions really violate RESTfulness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness)

If you want to know how properly build spring security service based REST examine this tutorial:

http://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

Hope that this helps.

**You are using formLogin security**, which means you need to add some kind of data store to authenticate users against it.

Here is an example for in-memory data store from spring documentation:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() throws Exception {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("user").password("password").roles("USER").build());
    manager.createUser(User.withUsername("admin").password("password").roles("USER","ADMIN").build());
    return manager;
}

}
```

according to this example, you suppose to authenticate successfully with a username of user and password of password

You are trying to apply security with angularJS as your front technology, there's a great tutorial how to achieve that, I already implemented it on my project, here's the link:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/

***For starter you need to use httpBasic and not formLogin as your security authentication method.***

Comment: I have tried with sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS). Request is going past UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter now. Issue is : .anyRequest().authenticated() returns false now and Access denied exception is thrown.

Comment: Do you have any data source (in-memory or database) to authenticate your users against it?

Comment: I am using default user provided by Spring Security - Spring Boot.

Comment: Please post your stack trace and your security configuration file

Comment: Still same exception Moshe. I tried inMemoryAuthentication set up and user gets authenticated successfully. Issue is second request after authentication still giving anonymous user.  Form based authentication requires sessions and hence I cannot use STATELESS clause. I tried without that also but still same exception

Comment: By the way if you are using angular js and spring you need to use http basic and not form login

Comment: I updated my answer, if you need further help, let me know @Atul

Answer (score 1):

After banging head for a long time , I am finally able to find out the solution.

Steps are : 
1) Form based login requires session to be established . When authentication succeeds , server sends  `Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=3974317C6DE34865B6726FCFD4C98C08; Path=/springbootrest; HttpOnly` header in response.

2)Browser has to send this header in every request else there will be no session established and authentication will fail

3)But since I was using `CORS` (my server and ui app reside on different port on local system) , browser was not sending `Cookie:JSESSIONID=3974317C6DE34865B6726FCFD4C98C08` in request failing the authentication.

4)I have to add below line  `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;` in my angular js client after that browser started sending above header in request.

5)At server side I have to add below code in CORSFilter.

```
 response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials","true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:8186");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, WWW-Authenticate, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, Version");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "X-Requested-With, WWW-Authenticate, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type");

       final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
       if("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
```