# Session alternatives in Microservices

Tags: java, rest, session, microservices

I have web client which invokes multiple services. As soon as the user is authenticated, I want to store the email Id somewhere as it sends the email Id for each request.

I don't want to use session as I have heard that is the best practice. In REST, all data must be sent for the request and it must be stateless. What other alternatives are there? Is using DB for session management still not breaking the stateless principle of REST?

I went through [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions) but there were many contradicting opinions there. Should the email Id be stored in session storage of the browser then?

Comment: What happens if the user changes the email ID? Emails sent to the wrong user?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do it with a authentication header. Check out these threads:

- [Do sessions really violate RESTfulness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068113/do-sessions-really-violate-restfulness)
- [If REST applications are supposed to be stateless, how do you manage sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105296/if-rest-applications-are-supposed-to-be-stateless-how-do-you-manage-sessions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Those links are just perfect.